# How can I customize the initial progress dialog in install4j?

Tags: install4j

By default an install4j installer has an initial dialog with progress, presumably for the unpacking of the installer's jre etc.  This progress dialog mentions install4j as the tool used to create the installer.  This can be suppressed in the project settings with the "Suppress initial progress dialog" check-box.

It's not really desirable to completely suppress this dialog, as the machine then sits there bogged down while things are being unzip'd with nothing presented to the user.

Ideally one could customize this dialog with company specific graphics/text etc.

Is this possible? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

The progress dialog is in the native part of the installer before the JVM is loaded, so customizing it is not as flexible as with installer screens. The displayed icon is the icon of the installer executable which can be customized by setting Installer->Screens & Actions->Installer->Executable Icon.

You can change messages on the progress dialog by going to General Settings->Languages, defining a custom localization file and overriding the message:

PrepareInstaller=Your own message

Comment: Thanks Ingo, that helps. Would be nice to allow for a simply custom splash graphic.  How do I get new feature feedback submitted?

Comment: @Frank Anywhere you can reach me :-) In fact we already have this in our issue tracker (splash screen for installer).